# R and ggplot: Trouble Labeling Stacked Bar Chart From Second Data Frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

```
plot_data  <-  rbind(
                      data.frame(year = seq(2018,2027), value = seq(1000,10000,1000), type = 'Type A'),
                      data.frame(year = seq(2018,2027), value = seq(500,5000,500), type = 'Type B')
                      )
plot_labels     <-  data.frame(year = seq(2018,2027), label = seq(1500,15000,1500))

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=as.character(year), y=value, fill=type)) +
geom_bar(width = .6, stat='identity') +
# geom_text(data = plot_labels, aes(x = year, y = text, label = label)) +
scale_x_discrete(name = '') +
scale_y_continuous(name = 'My Label\n') +
scale_fill_manual(name = '', values = c('red', 'blue')) +
theme(
  plot.title = element_text(size = 10, hjust = .5),
  panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = 'white', size = 1),
  panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = 'white'),
  plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
  axis.text.x = element_text(colour = 'grey20', size = 7, angle = 45, hjust = 1),
  axis.title.y = element_text(color = 'grey20', size = 9),
  axis.text.y = element_text(colour = 'grey20', size = 7),
  legend.position='bottom',
  legend.key.size=unit(5,'mm'),
  legend.text = element_text(size = 7))
```

This code will produce a stacked bar chart.

My goal is to label this plot with `plot_labels$label` on the same y axis and scale as the stacked bar.

Uncommenting out line beginning with `geom_text` in plot definition throws the following error:

`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'type' not found`

`plot_labels$label` values are equivalent to summarizing `plot_data$value` by `plot_data$year`.

Would much appreciate the help in troubleshooting!

Comment: You have to add `inherit.aes = FALSE` in the `geom_text()` line, otherwise it inherits `fill=type` from the aesthetic mapping defined in `ggplot()`, & tries to look for a column named "type" in `plot_labels`.

Comment: Also, I think it should be `y = label` rather than `y = text` in the aesthetic mapping for `geom_text()`?

Comment: `y = text` was a typo and a good catch on your part.  adding `inherit.aes = FALSE` worked!  What a swell guy, thanks!

Comment: @ErikKornet you mean girl. ;)

Comment: whoops!  sorry @Z.Lin and thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems: 
1) the `fill` should be placed in `geom_bar`, otherwise it will be inherited by all geoms that follow.
2) the `geom_col` is better than `geom_bar` when you provide both `x` and `y`.
3) in `geom_text`, `x` and `y` need to be the same type as in `ggplot`.

```
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=as.character(year), y=value)) +
    geom_col(aes(fill=type), width = .6) +
    geom_text(data = plot_labels, aes(x = as.character(year), y = label, label = label), vjust = 0) +
    scale_x_discrete(name = '') +
    scale_y_continuous(name = 'My Label\n') +
    scale_fill_manual(name = '', values = c('red', 'blue')) +
    theme(
        plot.title = element_text(size = 10, hjust = .5),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = 'white', size = 1),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = 'white'),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = 'grey20', size = 7, angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color = 'grey20', size = 9),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = 'grey20', size = 7),
        legend.position='bottom',
        legend.key.size=unit(5,'mm'),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 7))
```

Comment: sweet, thanks for the answer and suggestions!  Really got stuck on this plot for a while.